# Convert SQL query into Drupal 7 PHP rules

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-database

```
SELECT address
  FROM user_address
 WHERE username = '$user->name'
 ORDER BY time DESC
 LIMIT 1
```

Here is the SQL query that I can understand. How is it possible to convert it into Drupal's 7 PHP? I'm trying to figure that out for a day, and I tried different approaches, but it seems that I am just bad in that.

Comment: Use views module. Point of using CMS is avoiding custom code, custom queries etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`db_select`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7.x) :

```
$results = db_select('user_address', 'ua')
        ->fields('ua', array('address'))
        ->condition('ua.username', $user->name, '=')
        ->orderBy('ua.time', 'DESC')
        ->range(0,1)
        ->execute()
        ->fetchAll();
  var_dump($results);
```

Otherwise you can use [`db_query`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query/7.x) if you want to write entire SQL  :

```
$results = db_query("SELECT address
  FROM user_address
 WHERE username = :username
 ORDER BY time DESC
 LIMIT 1 ", array(':username' => $user->name))->fetchAll();

var_dump($results);
```

Finally you can use [`db_query_range`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query_range/7.x) :

```
$page = 0;
$limit = 1
$results = db_query_range("SELECT address
      FROM user_address
     WHERE username = :username
     ORDER BY time DESC", 
    $page * $limit, 
   $limit,   
   array(':username' => $user->name))
   ->fetchAll();

    var_dump($results);
```

Answer (score 0):

For that we use db_select() or db_query() - first one preferable.

```
 $query = db_select('user_address', 'u');

// Add condition and fields 
$query->condition('u.username', ‘james’)
 $query->fields('u’ array('u.address'));
```

// execute it

```
    $result = $query->execute();
   foreach ($result as $record) {
    // Do something with each $record
     }
```

For more see 
https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/database-api/dynamic-queries/introduction-to-dynamic-queries.

**update**: see condition portion. Also, you can put this in a module or php executable area of your site or via drush command line. 
Change the username James to match your need

Comment: Still error, even if I removed ` and replaced them with '', added a coma after fields('u' ->,<- array(

Comment: I shouldn’t have the ‘==‘.  It should have been without that since the default checks for equality or simply ‘=‘.  See updated answer (end of condition line)

Comment: Keep the single quote

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
$result = db_select('user_address', 'ua')
  ->fields('ua', array('address'))
  ->condition('ua.username', $user->name)
  ->execute()
  ->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
$result = $result = db_select('usr_address','u')
          ->fields('u',array('address','uid'))
          ->range(0,1)
    ->orderby('time', 'DESC')
          ->condition('u.uid',$uid,'=')
          ->execute();
```

here is how it actually worked.
Thank you for your suggestions, but at the end I made it. By myself. Well, kinda ;D